# There is any way to parse the JASPER Report into JSON Object..?

Tags: java, json, jasper-reports

I want to create a **JSON Object** from the JASPER Report by writing **Java** Code. is there is any way to do this??

Comment: Have you checked anything about your requirement on the internet(google)?

Comment: yes, i have checked, but not getting proper response.

Comment: similar kind of discussion happened in this link morover java implementation is not present, But some kind of help you will get from this link. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759503/can-we-stored-the-jasperreport-data-in-json-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759503/can-we-stored-the-jasperreport-data-in-json-object).

Comment: @idiotduffer It is a bad idea to repost the same question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, is is possible.
Take a look to [JasperReports documentation here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/subreport/index.html#jsonmetadataexport).
Note that the JSON output format organizes data hierachically in a tree structure, written in accordance with the JSON syntax:

- arrays are enclosed in square brackets
- objects in arrays are comma-separated
- objects are enclosed in curly braces
- object members come in name:value pairs, separated by commas

---

Here is [another topic](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-export-my-report-json-format) that may help you (with screenshots).